# CSS and JS height transition from unset to certain value

Tags: javascript

I have an element with unset height. I want it's height to transition smoothly into desired value (200px for example).
I use requestAnimationFrame for it, but I can't understand how does it work exactly.

In the example below, if we uncomment first requestAnimationFrame and it's closing brackets, it will work exactly the way we want it to. **But why?**

Yes, I do understand that in such a way the first height change will be wrapped in it's own requestAnimationFrame, but the key quesion is **why does it makes such a big difference**? The more so as we have the second height change already wrapped in requestAnimationFrame. Doesn't it already make it kind of separated in time apart from the first change?

I've read several articles about requestAnimationFrame but still couldn't understand this particular example. I guess I need some kind of handwavy explanation here.

Please, help.

**EDIT after receiving an answer:**

This edit is based on barhatsor's answer.

So basically in the original example the sequence of actions looks like this (correct me if I'm wrong):

Frame 1, action 1. (immediately). Find out real height of the element in pixels
Frame 1, action 2. (immediately). Set the element's height to it's scrollHeight
Frame 1, action 3. (immediately). Change the element's height to 200px (immediate change causes merging of changes)
Frame 2, action 1. (on the next frame). Browser, when you are ready, animate (changes merged - nothing to animate)

If we uncomment the first requestAnimationFrame and it's closing brackets, would it look like this?

Frame 1, action 1. (immediately). Find out real height of the element in pixels
Frame 1, action 2. (immediately). Set the element's height to it's scrollHeight
Frame 2, action 1. (on the next frame). Browser, when you are ready, animate
Frame 2, action 2. (immediately). Change the element's height to 200px (changes are now separated in time by one frame?)
Frame 3, action 1. (on the next frame). Browser, when you are ready, animate (animates change)

Is this correct? I would love to see your point of view on this. May be I am absolutely wrong?

```js
let button = document.querySelector(".button");
let element = document.querySelector(".element");

button.addEventListener("click", triggerHeightChange);

function triggerHeightChange() {
  // finding out real height of the element in pixels
  let actualHeight = element.scrollHeight; 
  
 // requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    // assgning height value so we aren't transitioning out of "auto"
    element.style.height = actualHeight + "px"; 
 
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      // assigning desired height value
      element.style.height = "200px"; 
    })
 // })
 
  // this part is just to return element to it's initial state after transition
  element.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
    element.style.height = actualHeight + "px";
    element.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
      element.removeAttribute("style");
    }, {once: true})
  }, {once: true})
}
```

```css
.element {
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: gold;
  transition: 0.5s height;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">Element with an unset height</div>

<button class="button">Change element's height from unset to 200px with smooth transition, then return it back</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the element's height to it's `scrollHeight` and then immediately changed it to `200px`.

Most browsers optimize transitions and will merge changes which take less than 16ms, which is why the transition was not showing.

So the solution is to tell the browser to animate when it's ready, using `requestAnimationFrame()`, like in your code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame